# cocos2d-x v 2.0.4 FATAL EXCEPTION GLThread when run on Android emulator

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-emulator, cocos2d-x

I create cocos2d-x app
I'm using cocos2d-2.0-x-2.0.4
I've got error when trying to run  app from Eclipse on Android emulator.

```
12-04 08:03:13.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1081): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 105
12-04 08:03:13.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1081): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No config chosen
12-04 08:03:13.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1081): at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$BaseConfigChooser.chooseConfig(GLSurfaceView.java:874)
12-04 08:03:13.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1081): at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.start(GLSurfaceView.java:1024)
12-04 08:03:13.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1081): at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1401)
12-04 08:03:13.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1081): at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
```

I set

```
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
```

in manifest.
I turned on gpu emulation for AVD.
I use API level 17 for AVD
I found discussion about that problem on cocos2d-x forum: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/boards/6/topics/12563
I have tried everything mentioned there without success.
What is a reason of that problem?
How can I fix it?

Comment: test your app on a real device might be better

Comment: I want to test my app on emulator to test how my app works on different screens.

Comment: couldn't help much then, actually our company bought a lot devices in deferent resolution.....

Comment: I solved this, see my answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved this rpoblem by adding

```
gLSurfaceView.setEGLConfigChooser(8 , 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
```

before

```
gLSurfaceView.setCocos2dxRenderer(new Cocos2dxRenderer());
```

in Cocos2dxActivity.java

Now my app runs on emulator.

My post on this link contains screenshot with AVD settings:

http://www.cocos2d-x.org/boards/6/topics/12563?r=19274#message-19274

Comment: Yes, this! I spent hours trying to track down the problem. The BasicGLSurfaceViewActivity SDK sample would not work on the emulator on Windows. Adding your call to setEGLConfigChooser before setRenderer in the BasicGLSurfaceView constructor fixed it. I'd give you more upvotes if I could!