# OpenGL ES 2.0 Support for Android?

Tags: android-emulator, opengl-es-2.0

Does the Android emulator support OpenGL ES 2.0? I've seen some people say "Yes, but you have to change a few settings." and I've also seen "No, it doesn't support it, period." Here's what I've done to try and correct the problem, including some error messages that I got.

First, I modified the AndroidManifest.xml to contain the following code:

```
<uses-feature 
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

Then, when I want to instantiate my GLSurfaceView, I use this sequence of code to instantiate it:

```
super(context);

setEGLContextClientVersion(2);

setRenderer(new MyRenderer());
setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
```

Then, everywhere I looked said that you must go into the AVD Manager, select the emulator, go to "Hardware", add "GPU emulation" and set the boolean to "yes". However, here is what I see when I look at mine:

[image: Screenshoot of my Android 4.2 emulator window.]

What's peculiar is that I have another emulator in my AVD Manager of which I do have the "Hardware" table:

[image: What does my Android 2.2 emulator have the hardware table?]

And just to show you exactly what I'm doing, here's some code that does some stuff I want to do in OpenGL ES 2.0 (I mainly got this from Android's own tutorials):

```
int vertexShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderCode);
int fragmentShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderCode);

program = GLES20.glCreateProgram();
GLES20.glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
GLES20.glAttachShader(program, fragmentShader);
GLES20.glLinkProgram(program);
```

I don't want to change my code back to work with OpenGL ES 1.0 because that will require a lot of headaches and if I can avoid it, I will.

Finally, when I try running my program, the program closes with the window: "Unfortunately,  has stopped." This is what LogCat told me:

```
12-05 06:16:27.165: E/AndroidRuntime(936): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 81
12-05 06:16:27.165: E/AndroidRuntime(936): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No config chosen
12-05 06:16:27.165: E/AndroidRuntime(936):  at    android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$BaseConfigChooser.chooseConfig(GLSurfaceView.java:874)
12-05 06:16:27.165: E/AndroidRuntime(936):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.start(GLSurfaceView.java:1024)
12-05 06:16:27.165: E/AndroidRuntime(936):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1401)
12-05 06:16:27.165: E/AndroidRuntime(936):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I can say Yes on your question.
Android emulator supports OpenGL ES 2.0.
I created an app with cocos2d-x v.2 (which uses OpenGL ES 2.0).
I had same FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 81  error with same stack.
I solved this issue by adding

```
gLSurfaceView.setEGLConfigChooser(8 , 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
```

before setting renderer setRenderer:

```
gLSurfaceView.setCocos2dxRenderer(new Cocos2dxRenderer());
```

Now I can run my app on Android emulator.

See my question and answer at  https://stackoverflow.com/a/13719983/307547.
My post on this link contains screenshot with AVD settings:

http://www.cocos2d-x.org/boards/6/topics/12563?r=19274#message-19274

Comment: Please note that hardware GPU acceleration works only on AVDs with Android 4.0 and up. AVD with Android 2.2 won't have accelerated OpenGL ES 2.0

Comment: I will try to test this code on Android devices today. I want to be sure that this code will work on real devices.

Comment: I tested this code on Fly device, and it works. People at cocos2d-x forum mentioned that this code should only be run on emulator, not on the device. See http://www.cocos2d-x.org/boards/6/topics/12563?r=19457#message-19457

Answer (score 5):

I just fixed the problem without adding any new lines to my source code. In the avd-manager i set "Use Host GPU" for my emulator device. Works now perfectly fine on my Geforce GTX 570.

API Level on emulator device is 16, and min-SDK in Manifest is 15.

Answer (score 4):

Got the same problem. Original Buggy Code:

```java
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Into onCreate Draw triangle");
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,  WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    if (detectOpenGLES20()){
        Log.d("GLES20", "GL ES 2.0 Supported..............!");
    } else {
        Log.d("GLES20", "GL ES 2.0 Not Supported...............!");
    }

    view = new GLSurfaceView(this);
    view.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
    view.setEGLConfigChooser(true);
    view.setRenderer(new TriangleRenderer(view));
    setContentView(view);
}
```

**Solved by :** 
a.) Replacing this code line

```java
view.setEGLConfigChooser(true);
```

with

```java
view.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
```

b.) Setting `-gpu on` via Eclipse --> Run as ---> Target ---> Additional Emulator Command Line Options

*Adding a little more to the above discussion:*
There were two different Exception messages I came across while working with the above piece of code

> FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 75
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No configs match configSpec

and

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No config chosen

A more detailed case study narrated at http://on-android-opengl2.blogspot.in/2013/05/android-opengl-es-20-emulator.html