# Error when running openGL ES 2.0 Android app on virtual device

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying to run an Android app with some openGL, following [this tutorial](http://www.jayway.com/2013/05/09/opengl-es-2-0-tutorial-for-android-part-i-getting-started/) and get this error:

```
04-29 12:40:39.075    1099-1115/org.xxxx.vumeterdemo.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 75
Process: org.xxxx.vumeterdemo.app, PID: 1099
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No config chosen
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$BaseConfigChooser.chooseConfig(GLSurfaceView.java:874)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.start(GLSurfaceView.java:1024)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1401)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
```

I'm running it on the default Nexus4 virtual device with the option "Use Host GPU" ticked. I use Android Studio 0.5.7 on Ubuntu 14.04.

What am I missing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14167319/android-opengl-demo-no-config-chosen

This might be of some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont know why but recently I face same problem when i just started with android app devel. This fixed issue for me when working with emulator

> super.setEGLConfigChooser(8 , 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);