# developer.android.com OpenGL es sample doesn't work?

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm following this tutorial: http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/environment.html

and trying to get it running throughout the whole day... In the meantime I was looking into some other tutorials about OpenGL but finally I always ended up with an application crash...
Here are all my files:
AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.openglproject1"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
    <supports-gl-texture android:name="GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture" />
    <supports-gl-texture android:name="GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.openglproject1.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.openglproject1.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

fragment_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.openglproject1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private GLSurfaceView mGLView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create a GLSurfaceView instance and set it
        // as the ContentView for this Activity.
        mGLView = new MyGLSurfaceView(this);
        setContentView(mGLView);
    }

    class MyGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {

        public MyGLSurfaceView(Context context){
            super(context);

         // Create an OpenGL ES 2.0 context
            setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
            // Set the Renderer for drawing on the GLSurfaceView
            setRenderer(new MyGLRenderer());
         // Render the view only when there is a change in the drawing data
            setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
        }
    }

}
```

MyGLRenderer.java:

```
package com.example.openglproject1;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.opengl.GLES20;

public class MyGLRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {
        // Redraw background color
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height) {
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 arg0, EGLConfig arg1) {
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    }
}
```

And according to developer.android.com this should work and display a gray screen. I'm able to compile the app and launch it on emulator but it immediately crashes... Does anybody see any issues in these code snippets? I'm already exhasuted trying to run 1 stupid OpenGL app for the whole day...
Here's the logcat:

```
06-27 13:58:16.901: D/(1075): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8946c38, tid 1075
06-27 13:58:16.971: W/EGL_emulation(1075): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-27 13:58:16.981: D/OpenGLRenderer(1075): Enabling debug mode 0
06-27 13:58:17.081: D/(1075): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb894f3d0, tid 1088
06-27 13:58:17.141: W/dalvikvm(1075): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2a97ba8)
06-27 13:58:17.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1075): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 78
06-27 13:58:17.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1075): Process: com.example.openglproject1, PID: 1075
06-27 13:58:17.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1075): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No config chosen
06-27 13:58:17.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1075):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$BaseConfigChooser.chooseConfig(GLSurfaceView.java:874)
06-27 13:58:17.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1075):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.start(GLSurfaceView.java:1024)
06-27 13:58:17.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1075):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1401)
06-27 13:58:17.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1075):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
06-27 13:58:24.351: I/Process(1075): Sending signal. PID: 1075 SIG: 9
06-27 14:22:48.651: D/(1120): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb894b288, tid 1120
06-27 14:22:48.691: W/EGL_emulation(1120): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-27 14:22:48.701: D/OpenGLRenderer(1120): Enabling debug mode 0
06-27 14:22:48.771: D/(1120): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb894f420, tid 1133
06-27 14:22:48.821: W/dalvikvm(1120): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2a97ba8)
06-27 14:22:48.841: E/AndroidRuntime(1120): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 81
06-27 14:22:48.841: E/AndroidRuntime(1120): Process: com.example.openglproject1, PID: 1120
06-27 14:22:48.841: E/AndroidRuntime(1120): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No config chosen
06-27 14:22:48.841: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$BaseConfigChooser.chooseConfig(GLSurfaceView.java:874)
06-27 14:22:48.841: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.start(GLSurfaceView.java:1024)
06-27 14:22:48.841: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1401)
06-27 14:22:48.841: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
06-27 14:22:55.231: I/Process(1120): Sending signal. PID: 1120 SIG: 9
06-27 14:23:08.541: D/(1160): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb894ba50, tid 1160
06-27 14:23:08.591: W/EGL_emulation(1160): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-27 14:23:08.601: D/OpenGLRenderer(1160): Enabling debug mode 0
06-27 14:23:08.661: D/(1160): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb894f4f0, tid 1173
06-27 14:23:08.691: W/dalvikvm(1160): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2a97ba8)
06-27 14:23:08.691: E/AndroidRuntime(1160): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 84
06-27 14:23:08.691: E/AndroidRuntime(1160): Process: com.example.openglproject1, PID: 1160
06-27 14:23:08.691: E/AndroidRuntime(1160): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No config chosen
06-27 14:23:08.691: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$BaseConfigChooser.chooseConfig(GLSurfaceView.java:874)
06-27 14:23:08.691: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.start(GLSurfaceView.java:1024)
06-27 14:23:08.691: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1401)
06-27 14:23:08.691: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
06-27 14:23:10.811: I/Process(1160): Sending signal. PID: 1160 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Please post any exceptions you see in your logcat.

Comment: logcat added but it's still unclear to me

Comment: Potential duplicate of [Android OpenGL demo “No config chosen”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14167319/android-opengl-demo-no-config-chosen)

Comment: Eventually... Thanks a lot! It's just so incredible to me how nobody managed to fix those tutorials on developer.android.com... Btw now the application starts normally but displays the same message "Unfortunatelly, the application has stopped" after I quit it. Is there still sth wrong or it should behave this way at this stage?

Comment: Well if it is crashing, I would assume there is still something wrong. Your logcat should again be able to help you find the cause of the crash.

Comment: I recreated the emulator and now everything works as expected without a crash. Once again thanks for your help

Comment: Do you have a real device you can use for development? If you do, I would suggest using that instead of the emulator. I know it's supposed to work, but I never had much luck trying to do OpenGL development with the emulator.