# Android MediaCodec h.264 Decoding Surface Mode Color Banding

Tags: android, opengl-es, h.264, android-mediacodec, surface

I am using Android's MediaCodec API to decode and play live and raw H.264 video stream. My target device is a PC, running on Android-x86 6.0. The PC is running on a Intel® Celeron® Processor N2930 CPU.

When I set the decoder to surface mode and render the video to a TextureView, I am experiencing some color banding issues.

When I set the decoder to use ByteBuffer mode, and then save the decoded video frames to a file, then open the file on another computer, I found no color banding issues with the video frames.

Running out of ideas, then I tried to implement my own OpenGL ES view to render the video. Got it to work, but color banding is still there. Then I save the decoded frames from the OpenGL ES view renderer using GLES20.glReadPixels(), and when I open those frames on another computer, I see the color banding in the frames.

More observations:
1) I used the bundled video player (Video player) and MX Player to played some video files. Both the bundled video player and MX Player (in HW decoding mode) experienced the same color banding issue.

2) Playback in SW decoding mode in MX Player shows no color banding.

Tried almost all suggestions available on the web to no avail. Please help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What framebuffer format are you rendering into for the surface view? Banding is normally indicative that you are rendering into a 16-bit render target (e.g. RGB 565) rather than the more usual 32-bit target (RBGA8).

Comment: @solidpixel...For the OpenGL rendering view, basically I used the code at http://code.metager.de/source/xref/android/4.0.3/cts/tests/src/android/media/cts/VideoSurfaceView.java with some minor modifications to connect to the rest of the app. Shamefully, I have no idea where to set the framebuffer format. Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: @solidpixel... By the way, rendering the video using TextureView or even the SurfaceView presents the same color banding issue. It seems that as long as I'm using the decoder in Surface mode I am having this issue. Using the decoder in ByteBuffer mode, saving the image and viewing it seems fine.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to do this for VideoViews - but for GL this is the usual approach:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14167319/android-opengl-demo-no-config-chosen

Comment: @solidpixel... Put super.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0) in the constructor of the WindowsSurfaceView as some recommended in the link you gave. Still, the outcome of the video exhibits color banding.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to circumvent the problem by using MediaCodec in ByteBuffer (software) mode.