# Cannot 'Hello World' in Cocos2d-x

Tags: java, android, eclipse, cocos2d-x, emulation

I am trying to setup Cocos2d-x for some game development. After creating a default Hello World project and importing the Cocos2d-x libraries into Eclipse, when I just try to run the app on the emulator, it crashes down. Please help in this regard.

I have enabled GPU emulation in the emulator, added the OpenGLES 2.0 permission in the manifest file.

```
package com.toddperkins.MoleItx;
import org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxActivity;
import org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MoleItx extends Cocos2dxActivity{

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
}

public Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView onCreateView() {
    Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView glSurfaceView = new Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView(this);
    // MoleItx should create stencil buffer
    glSurfaceView.setEGLConfigChooser(5, 6, 5, 0, 16, 8);

    return glSurfaceView;
}

static {
    System.loadLibrary("cocos2dcpp");
}     
}
```

LogCat :

```
`05-26 15:06:18.048: D/dalvikvm(453): Added shared lib/ data/data/com.toddperkins.MoleItx/lib/libcocos2dcpp.so 0x405132a8
 05-26 15:06:18.246: D/Cocos2dxActivity(453): model=sdk
 05-26 15:06:18.246: D/Cocos2dxActivity(453): product=sdk
 05-26 15:06:18.246: D/Cocos2dxActivity(453): isEmulator=true
 05-26 15:06:18.716: D/libEGL(453): egl.cfg not found, using default config
 05-26 15:06:18.716: D/libEGL(453): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
 05-26 15:06:18.861: W/dalvikvm(453): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
 05-26 15:06:18.866: E/AndroidRuntime(453): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 10
 05-26 15:06:18.866: E/AndroidRuntime(453): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No configs match configSpec
 05-26 15:06:18.866: E/AndroidRuntime(453):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$BaseConfigChooser.chooseConfig(GLSurfaceView.java:763)
 05-26 15:06:18.866: E/AndroidRuntime(453):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.start(GLSurfaceView.java:919)
 05-26 15:06:18.866: E/AndroidRuntime(453):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1264)
 05-26 15:06:18.866: E/AndroidRuntime(453):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1118)
 05-26 15:11:19.011: I/Process(453): Sending signal. PID: 453 SIG: 9`
```

Answer (score 1):

[Petr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/307547/petr), another Cocos2d-x user on StackOverflow, was able to fix this by [setting his GL configuration explicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13719983/881615), adding:

```
gLSurfaceView.setEGLConfigChooser(8 , 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
```

before

```
gLSurfaceView.setCocos2dxRenderer(new Cocos2dxRenderer());
```

Comment: `gLSurfaceView.setEGLConfigChooser` already exists. I have updated my question with the code. Please see it.